# validator.w3.org Error: Element style not allowed as child of element body in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Tags: html

```
<!doctype html>
<html  lang="en">
<head>
  <title>My Resume</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
<!-- prgWebPage.html - My Resume Site
        Written by: Rob Nelson nelsonj15@csp.edu
        Written: 3/10/17
        Revised: ???
  -->
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Rob Nelson</h1>

<!-- This is where my photo will be displayed -->
<img src="graphic/myPortrait.jpg" alt="A portrait of myself." />

<hr>
<h1>Professional Goal</h1>
<p>Greetings To All,</p>

<p>My name is Rob Nelosn, and a professional goal of mine is to gradute with my B.S. in Computer Sciences here at Concordia.
```

I believe this goal will not only enrich my personal development, but will give me tools I can implement into my career in the future. 
I am currently working with a non-profit in Saint Paul, MN and I have used a few computer oriented skills since I was hired in 2014. 
I hope to take the skills from this program to bolster my resume, and overall work portfolio, and ability.

```
<hr>

<h2>Work Experience</h2>

<hr>

<p><strong>New Lens Urban Mentoring Society Saint Paul, Minnesota   08/2014-Current Outreach and Partnership Coordinator</strong>
<br>Recruiting/Retaining Mentors for the program, Office Management, Website development, Social Media Development (Facebook, various blog sites)
</p>

<p><strong>Green Iowa AmeriCorps Dubuque, Iowa  08/2013-08/2014 Marketing Coordinator</strong><br>
```

Maintaining, and managing all fascists of social media.(Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, Monthly Newsletter, Company Website) My job also consisted of our primary focus which was Home Energy Audits, and Weatherizations. In addition I also helped with education events, outreach events, and other volunteer management projects.

```
<p><strong>The Busted Lift Dubuque, Iowa    08/2013-08/2014 Bartender</strong>       <br>
```

Serve drinks, and cater to patron's needs as they arrive at the bar.

```
<p><strong>United States Army National Guard    06/2005-06/2009 46QPublic Affairs Specialist Journalist</strong><br>
```

Research, prepare and disseminate news releases, articles, Web-based material and photographs on Army personnel and activities.

```
<hr>

<h3>Education</h3>

<p><strong>York Technical College Rock hill, SC 2007 - 2009</strong><br>
```

Art with a focus on Music, GPA: 3.6

```
<p><strong>Concordia University Saint Paul, MN 2015 - Present</strong><br>
```

Computer Science Major, GPA: 3.54

```
</p>

<h4>Skills</h4> 

<hr>
<p>
```

Public Speaking : Public Speaking 101, 102
Fund raising/Grant Writing : Wrote several grants for Green Iowa AmeriCorps (one    for the company’s first billboard)
    Writing/Editing : Creative writing for 4 years in High School Creative Writing       101-110
    Business/Entrepreneur : Micro Econ, Macro Econ
    Fine Arts/Crafts : Music History 101, Art Theory
    Proficient in Microsoft Word, Power Point, and Publisher
    2 years experience performing Energy Audits, and Low Impact Home          Weartherizations

```
<hr>


<style type="text/css">

table{
     border:                1px solid black;
     font-family:           times new roman;
     }
     td, th {
     padding:               10px;

     text-align:            center;
     vertical-align:        bottom; 
}    

</div></style>


<table>


<tr>
<td><strong>My Hobbies</strong></td>
<td><strong>My Current Classes</strong></td></tr>

<tr>
<td>Video Games</td><td>Modern Web Design CSC 135</tr>


<tr>
<td>Guitar</td><td>Introduction to Psychology Psy 101</tr>


</table>
</body>
```

Comment: I have been changing the position of <div> inside and outside the <style and have still been getting an error. Hopefully someone can help me figure this our as this is the last error I have to get rid of .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here:

```
<hr>


<style type="text/css">

table{
     border:                1px solid black;
     font-family:           times new roman;
     }
     td, th {
     padding:               10px;

     text-align:            center;
     vertical-align:        bottom; 
}    

</div></style>


<table>
```

You have close tag `</div>`  before close  that is not allowed. additionally try to put your styles in head section instead inside the body

Comment: Awesome! thanks  I moved it all into the head section and the error went *poof!